# Every integer valued Cauchy sequence is ultimately constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Question: Let $x(_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence and assume that $x_n \in ℕ$ for all $n \in ℕ$. Show that there is an integer $n_0$ such that $x_{n_0} = x_n$ for all $ n \ge n_0 $

proof.  (I'm not sure how to start or where to go from here)

Since $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy, it is bounded so the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem implies that there is a converging subsequence  $x(_{m_k})_k$ and $(x_n)_n$ itself converges.

Comment: Think of the definition of Cauchy sequences. Does "for all real $\epsilon > 0$" ring a bell?

Comment: @ParthKohli yes, there exists $N \in ℕ$ such that for all n, m, $\in$ N $|x_n - x_m| \le ϵ$

Comment: It is for all $n,m ≥ N$. Then take $\epsilon = 1/2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll let you complete the proof, but we're given two facts about the sequence:

- It's a Cauchy sequence, implying that we can find a certain point after which all elements are within an arbitrary distance of each other (that could be as small as you want, say of the order $10^{-10}$). Think what the sequence will be like *after* this point.

> Every element is a natural number, and natural numbers occur in discrete gaps of $1$. Then the only way a set of natural numbers can be arbitrarily close to each other is if they are equal.

Comment: how to I include the statement in the yellow box in my proof? is there a way to show that or can you just state it?

Comment: Yes. For $m, n \in \mathbb N$, $|m - n| \ge 1$ if $m \ne n$. So if $\epsilon = 10^{-{10}}$ (or any other real that is sufficiently close to zero), then for $|m - n| \le \epsilon$ to happen, the only possibility is $m = n$.